# Is there a way to take influence on behavior of bash history?

Tags: bash

In terminal the bash history is often helpful when you are searching for a command-line that you already used. But is there a way to influence the behavior of the bash history (i.e. which commands are saved, how long they are saved, how many are saved and so on)?

Comment: Hi! You may look *man history* up, then ask a concrete question! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several variables control the behaviour of your history:

- `HISTCONTROL`: controls how values are saved in your history. The values `ignorespace`, `ignoredups` and `erasedups` can entered here (separate them by colon).
- `HISTFILE`: sets the location of the history file.
- `HISTFILESIZE`: sets the maximum number of lines in your history file.
- `HISTIGNORE`: has a list of pattern which the bash ignores (see [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18842/is-there-a-way-to-take-influence-on-behavior-of-bash-history/18845#18845) for syntax).
- `HISTSIZE`: contains a number of lines which are remembered in the actual shell.
- `HISTTIMEFORMAT`: contains an expression how an entry is formatted (see [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18842/is-there-a-way-to-take-influence-on-behavior-of-bash-history/18849#18849))

Answer (score 3):

**Setting timestamp for history:**

- By default, history do not append with timestamp, but it is easy to configure it to display timestamp, you just need to set one environment variable **HISTTIMEFORMAT**.

  `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h/%d - %H:%M:%S "`
- Execute history again to see the result. 
  [image]
- If you dont want to save the commands in history,then

  `export HISTSIZE=0`

**VARIABLES:**

- HISTFILE - Controls where the history file gets saved.
- HISTFILESIZE - Controls how many history commands to keep in HISTFILE.
- HISTSIZE - Controls how many history commands to keep in the history list of current session.
- HISTIGNORE - Controls which commands to ignore and not save to the history list.

**Note:**

- You will loss your settings once you close your terminal.So if you want it to have permanently then you should add the above command to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a line like

```
export HISTFILESIZE=5000
```

to your `~/.bashrc` to increase the size of the history. By default commands started with a space are not saved. That is due to the `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` that is globally enabled in ubuntu by default.

You can also ignore commands starting with `l` or `which` by using

```
export HISTIGNORE="l*:which*"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to tell history NOT to remember a command: just start with a space.
There is also a very easy way te retrieve a specific command: type CTRL+R and a word from the command you are searching for.

There is certainly a way to increase the default history which is 500 lines by defaults... but I don't know how, sorry!